# Probabilistic inequality for sum of squares of zero mean Gaussian random variables

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. standard normal random variables. How to show that there is constant $c>0$ such that for every $a_k>0$ and for every $n>0$: $P(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kX_k^2>\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k+c\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2})>c$

Comment: Such problems are known as "small ball probabilities". Checkout Theorem 8.1 of this manuscript by Rudelson et al. http://www-personal.umich.edu/~rudelson/papers/rv-smallball.pdf

Comment: Also related are chi-squared variables[1] and their tail inequalities[2]. [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution  [2] https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables